# Slow query. Wrong database structure?

Tags: mysql

I have a database with table that contains tasks. Tasks have a lifecycle. The status of the task's lifecycle can change. These state transitions are stored in a separate table tasktransitions.
Now I wrote a query to find all open/reopened tasks and recently changed tasks but I already see with a rather small number of tasks (<1000) that execution time has becoming very long (>0.5s).

Tasks

```
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| taskid      | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| description | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Tasktransitions

```
+------------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field            | Type      | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+------------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| tasktransitionid | int(11)   | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| taskid           | int(11)   | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                |
| status           | int(11)   | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                |
| description      | text      | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| userid           | int(11)   | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| transitiondate   | timestamp | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
+------------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

Query

```
SELECT tasks.taskid,tasks.description,tasklaststatus.status
FROM tasks
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT tasktransitions.taskid,tasktransitions.transitiondate,tasktransitions.status
    FROM tasktransitions
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT taskid,MAX(transitiondate) AS lasttransitiondate
        FROM tasktransitions
        GROUP BY taskid
    ) AS tasklasttransition ON tasklasttransition.lasttransitiondate=tasktransitions.transitiondate AND tasklasttransition.taskid=tasktransitions.taskid
) AS tasklaststatus ON tasklaststatus.taskid=tasks.taskid
WHERE tasklaststatus.status IS NULL OR tasklaststatus.status=0 or tasklaststatus.transitiondate>'2013-09-01';
```

A more readable, less descriptive version of the query above:

```
SELECT t.taskid, t.description,ls.status
FROM tasks AS t
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT tt.taskid, tt.transitiondate, tt.status
    FROM tasktransitions AS tt
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT taskid,MAX(transitiondate) AS transitiondate
        FROM tasktransitions
        GROUP BY taskid
    ) AS lt USING (taskid,transitiondate)
) AS ls USING (taskid)
WHERE ls.status IS NULL OR ls.status=0 or ls.transitiondate>'2013-09-01';
```

I'm wondering if the database structure is best choice performance wise. Could adding indexes help? I already tried to add some but I don't see great improvements.

```
+-----------------+------------+----------------+--------------+------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table           | Non_unique | Key_name       | Seq_in_index | Column_name      | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-----------------+------------+----------------+--------------+------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| tasktransitions |          0 | PRIMARY        |            1 | tasktransitionid | A         |         896 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| tasktransitions |          1 | taskid_date_ix |            1 | taskid           | A         |         896 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| tasktransitions |          1 | taskid_date_ix |            2 | transitiondate   | A         |         896 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| tasktransitions |          1 | status_ix      |            1 | status           | A         |           3 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-----------------+------------+----------------+--------------+------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Any other suggestions?

Comment: To clarify - the aim is to select all opened OR reopened OR recenlty updated tasks?

Comment: The great thing about table aliases is that they prevent SQL from marching off the RHS of the page.  You can designate, for example, `FROM Tasks AS K` and then use `K.TaskID` instead of `tasks.taskid`, and more significantly, `FROM TaskTransitions AS T` and then `T.TransitionDate` instead of `TaskTransitions.TransitionDate` (where you can ignore my capitalization as you prefer).  Queries where you have to scroll horizontally to see the rest of what it said are painful.

Comment: Have you tried to split your query into two then UNION the results?  Specifically, get rid of the `LEFT JOIN` for records where `status=0 OR transitiondate >` .  Then `UNION` to a LEFT JOIN query where there are no tasktransitions (i.e., `status IS NULL`) _the 2nd query should be a simpler LEFT JOIN because you don't need to find the max(date) right?_

Answer (score 0):

Not tested and not sure if this was your aim, but uses only one subquery.

```
SELECT 
    tasks.taskid, tasks.description, 
    (SELECT MAX(transitiondate) 
    FROM tasktransitions WHERE tasktransitions.taskid=tasks.id) lasttransitiondate
FROM tasks
LEFT JOIN tasktransitions tt ON tt.taskid = tasks.id
WHERE tt.tasktransitionid IS NULL 
    OR tt.tasktransitionid = 0 
    OR tt.transitiondate > '2013-09-01';
```

To avoid the subquery at all, you could add a `last_trasition_id` foreign key to the `tasks` table and update it on every transition change by using a trigger on insert into the `tasktransitions`.

Comment: This query doesn't do the same thing the original query is doing. It does not look for the latest transition status. This query joins all transitions and then checks if one is 0, not only the latest one. ps: I think you mean `tt.status is NULL` istead of `tt.tasktransitionid is NULL`

Comment: You are right. But what about an extra column that holds this information? This will speed up the query a lot. The current status of a task seems natural to be an attribute of a task and if is needed often - it shouldn't be calculated on the fly in such complicated query.